# Laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 crashed and won't load now

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2

So my laptop crashed and I had to shut it down with the power button. After sometime,I open it up again to see the grub menu https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUKbp.png Then I selected Ubuntu and tried to load it and nothing happened,only the purple screen for so long,powered off,on again,then in the grub menu I went to advanced option,loaded the first one, something like Linux 4.4.0-148-generic and still nothing happened. I don't want to lose the data stored (so many important stuff), please help!

Comment: In the advanced options, the first entry is the same as the standard "Ubuntu" entry. Try the third entry. If that doesn't fix the issue, select the first entry and press e. Navigate to the line that contains `quiet splash $vt_handoff` and remove those three words. Press F10 to boot and tell us if there are any errors.

Comment: Third entry worked (142 version). What was the problem though?

Comment: If you are stuck with the purple scree, press ESC and you will be shown status messages. Usually you can get info from there. For now you may take a look at `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log` and see if you can make something out of the messages.

Comment: If booting an older kernel worked, there is probably a problem with the latest kernel. This could be a bug in the kernel, or something on your computer is incompatible with the latest kernel version. Try the other suggestion (removing `quiet splash $vt_handoff` from first entry) to see what goes wrong. By the way what did you do before ubuntu crashed?

Comment: Uhm guys,I updated my os and then  typed in sudo apt autoremove and apparently it deleted the 142 version and now when I start the lappy again, it's just the purple screen and nothing else,not even the grub menu!!! I feel so screwed rn.